# How to mimic a UITableView using UICollectionViewLayout?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionView`, which I would like to give the appearance of a `UITableView` on smaller devices. There are various tutorials online about using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to mimic it by setting each cell's width to that of the collection view, but someone suggested to me that the "proper" solution is to subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` and implement the desired positioning. I've found fewer examples and resources online dealing with `UICollectionViewLayout`, however. How could this be best implemented?

Comment: Just make cell's width as screen width and it should work.

Comment: could you explain, why using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is not a proper solution for that? Using this would be the same as subclassing `UICollectionViewLayout` or not?

Comment: first of all 2 different cell or use single cell dynamically for collection view, collection (table view type). Use collectionViewLayout delegate method to handle the size of the cell and add a device specific condition here.

Comment: No, guys. The question is about using `UICollectionViewLayout`, NOT abusing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout `.